# How to implement window functions in structured streaming for a batch usecase?

Tags: pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks, spark-structured-streaming, databricks-sql

First some background, I recently had to move my pipelines from standard reading and writing to structured streaming after some business requirements to merge all our pipelines at a central place.
The operations I do are, read data from `source` container, do some transformations on the data, save it as table in `staging`, then move data to `analytics` layer after some other transformations.

I was using the code:

```
df = spark.read.parquet(path)
transformed_df = do_transformations(df, primary_keys, transformation_name)
saveAsTable_tostaging() //
```

I updated the above code:

```
df = {spark.readStream.format.options.schema.load //}
transformed_df = do_transformations(df, primary_keys, transformation_name)
streaming_query = { transformed_df.writeStream.trigger ///}

Pseudo code for read and write streams. Note, the readStream() and writeStream() operations
are part of the central place and I cannot change them as other teams are also using it. 
I can only update my transformation() function. However, I am allowed to update the trigger details of the writeStream, which I changed to "once":True
```

For my usecase, the pipeline is running once every day at `4AM`. There is no actual streaming job for my usecase as we only get data once every day, that is why it is still being treated as a batch job and runs once and stops.
After the changes almost all my transformations still function properly, and the entire read / write flow is also working properly, but there is 1 transformation which keeps failing.

The transformation: There are some specific fields in the `df`, let's call them `'additive-fields'` which must be `summed` for all `keys`. First, I need to check if the `table already exists` in `staging`. If yes, then I need to read the `staging` table and do the `sum` operation on the union of `staging table` and `df` on the same fields, if no, then I just need to do the `sum` operation on the `df` and then a single record per key should be sent to `staging` with the sum of these `'additive-fields'`

For eg, Let `df` =

```
|Key1| Key2| Nm1 | Nm2 | AdditiveField1| AdditiveField2| Db_timestamp| source_ts|
|----|-----|-----|-----|---------------|---------------|-------------|----------|
|A   |B    | Car | Bike| 10            | -0.02         |20231201     |20231127  |
|A   |B    |Taxi |Cycle|4              |-0.06          |20231201     |20231128  |
|B   |C    |Xyz  |ABC  |1              |-20            |20231201     |20231128  |
```

`Staging_table` =

```
|Key1|Key2|Nm1|Nm2|AdditiveField1|AdditiveField2|Db_timestamp|source_ts|
|--- |----|---|---|--------------|--------------|------------|---------|
| B  | C  |Old|PQR|       7      |       1      |  20231120  | 20231101|
```

`Here, Key1, Key2 are the keys, NM* are the normal fields on which I just have to take the latest record sorted by source_ts, and the additive fields need to be summed.` 

The desired output is:

```
|Key1|Key2|Nm1 | Nm2 |AdditiveField1|AdditiveField2|Db_timestamp|source_ts|
|----|----|----|-----|--------------|--------------|------------|---------|
| A  | B  |Taxi|Cycle|      14      |   -0.08      | 20231201   | 20231128|
| B  | C  |Xyz | ABC |       8      |    -19       | 20231201   | 20231128|
```

**EDIT: Sorry, unable to fix the table structure in the question. The df, staging_df and ouput look like this** https://prnt.sc/l3OuqsEWgGX-

When, I was using standard read and write I was easily able to implement this using:

```
def implement_additive_fields(df, table_name, primary_keys: list, fields: list):

    if check_tableExists(table_name): # returns true if table exists in staging else false.
        stmt = f"select * from {table_name}"
        staging_df = spark.sql(stmt)
        df = df.union(staging_df)

    window = Window.partitionBy(primary_keys).orderBy('source_ts').rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.unboundedFollowing)

    For i in fields: #these are the additive fields in the df
        df = df.withColumn(i, F.sum(i).over(window))

    df = df.withColumn('rank', F.row_number().over(window)).filter(F.col('rank')==1).drop(F.col('rank'))

   return df
```

After implementing the structured streaming, I understand that I can no longer use these `window functions` on my `df` and I need to use the `window functions` available for `structured streaming` which have some time parameters, but I cannot understand how to implement them as I am running this job still as a `batch` (once every day) and then it closes. There is no actual streaming job going on for these tables and I want to `sum` on records coming from the `staging` table as well as the streamed `df`.

Comment: Sorry, can't seem to fix table format in the question. The df, staging_df and output look like this https://prnt.sc/l3OuqsEWgGX-

Answer (score 0):

You can use `foreachBatch` to call a function and perform transformations.

Modify your function like this:

```py
def implement_additive_fields(df, table_name, primary_keys: list, fields: list):

    if check_tableExists(table_name):
        stmt = f"select * from {table_name}"
        staging_df = spark.sql(stmt)
        df = df.union(staging_df)

    window1 = Window.partitionBy(primary_keys).orderBy(F.desc('source_ts'))
    window2 = Window.partitionBy(primary_keys).orderBy('source_ts')

    for i in fields:
        df = df.withColumn(i, F.sum(i).over(window2))

    df = df.withColumn('rank', F.row_number().over(window1)).filter(F.col('rank')==1).drop(F.col('rank'))
    df.write.saveAsTable("tmp_staged")
    print("Done")
```

And call it like this:

```py
primary_keys=['Key1','Key2']
fields=['AdditiveField1','AdditiveField2']
stream_df = spark.readStream.schema(schema=schema).format("csv").option("header","true").load("/csvs/")
stream_df.writeStream.option("checkpointlocation","tmpcheckpointloc").foreachBatch(lambda df,id: implement_additive_fields(df,table_name,primary_keys=primary_keys,fields=fields)).trigger(once=True).start().awaitTermination()
```

Here is the input data used:

| Key1 | Key2 | Nm1 | Nm2 | AdditiveField1 | AdditiveField2 | Db_timestamp | source_ts |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | Car | Bike | 10 | -0.02 | 20231201 | 20231127 |
| A | B | Taxi | Cycle | 4 | -0.06 | 20231201 | 20231128 |
| B | C | Xyz | ABC | 1 | -2.0 | 2023431201 | 20231128 |

Output:

[image: Output table]

| Key1 | Key2 | Nm1 | Nm2 | AdditiveField1 | AdditiveField2 | Db_timestamp | source_ts |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | Taxi | Cycle | 14 | -0.08 | 20231201 | 20231128 |
| B | C | Xyz | ABC | 8 | -1 | 2023431201 | 20231128 |

Comment: Hi @JayashankarGS, thank you for the answer, though I know about ForEachBatch, I still can't use it, as I mentioned the read stream and the write stream are the part of the central pipeline and I cannot change them. I need to figure out how to do this task on the 'transformed_df' which is a streamed dataframe. I am looking for a solution through which I can manipulate the streaming window function in such a way to achieve my goal. The current write stream function is transformed_df.writeStream().option(checkpoint//).table(table_name)

Comment: Non time based window are not supported on streaming data. However you can't union the dataframe you read from staging table with streaming data when you call the function. I guess you need to check about session window and group by transformation but still you can't union staging data and streaming data. So possible answer is need do with each batch you are getting in streaming data.

Comment: I will update if any approach works.